# Expectation of absolute value of a function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Let x be real valued random variable taking values on $a_1,\ldots, a_n$. Let $\Pr(x=a_i)=p_i$. Let $f$ be real valued function defined on $a_1, \ldots, a_n$

It is known that
$$
E(f(x))=\sum_{i=1}^nf(a_i)p_i.
$$

Would be the same formula true for $E(|f(x)|)$, i. e.
$$
E(|f(x)|)=\sum_{i=1}^n|f(a_i)|p_i?
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. As $|f|$ is "a real valued function, defined on ..." .. just apply your formula to $|f|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ g(x) := |f(x)| $ be defined on $ a_1, \dots, a_n $. The composition of two real valued functions is a real valued function.

Now computing $E(g(x))$...